# Are gods of religions like Islam, Christianity etc be remembered after the end of Yuga?

Tags: yuga, other-religions, kali-yuga

Actually, at the end of every Yuga, everything is said to be collapsed. But it is a wonder that the most of the scriptures and the Rama setu bridge hadn't been collapsed.
There might have been a lot of good people, pure souls like the gods of other religions in Dwapara Yuga, Treta Yuga etc but still we do not know them. We only know Rama, Krishna and some avatars related to them. But some how they are related to the Hindu.

Does these religions exist after the end of the yuga?

Comment: actually is it not believed that it is only at the end of a kalpa that there is destruction. Not at the end of each Yuga. However each sect could have their own beliefs, I am unsure of this.

Comment: @Sai The entire Bhuloka is only destroyed at the end of the Kalpa.  But at the end of the Kali Yuga there is still the coming of Kalki who kills the evil people.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Oh yes, the OP however seems to be talking of a 'collapse that occurs' in each 'yuga' rather than only for kali yuga. Hence confused.

Comment: There is devastation after each Manvantara(ex:Matsya avatara), each kalpa (end of Brahma's day) and vikalpa (end of Brahma's life). First two are partial and on the last whole universe is gone.

Comment: @srinivasacaryadasa At the end of each kalpa earth is destroyed and at end vikalpa universe is destroyed. But what exactly is destroyed at the end of Manvantara? i didn't read Matsya purana but according to this TV series ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Puran_(TV_series)#Matsya_Avatara_and_the_theft_of_the_Vedas_.28episodes_7-9.29 ) Brahma requests Shiva to flood the earth with water and vishnu saves good people by manifesting as Matysa Avatar.

Comment: Bhavishya purana talks about mohammed as mahamada who is actually rebirth of tarakasura ,  whose religion will be killed in kaliyuga. But all other scriptures talk about religions survive only in 10,000 years of kaliyuga.Then there would be only atheists. During end of kaliyuga , we could see  only athiests . No religion would survive till then

Answer (score 5):

[Srimad Bhagavatham](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/2/12-16) says,

> By the time the Age of Kali ends, the bodies of all creatures will be greatly reduced in size, and the religious principles of followers of varṇāśrama will be ruined. The path of the Vedas will be completely forgotten in human society, and so-called religion will be mostly atheistic. The kings will mostly be thieves, the occupations of men will be stealing, lying and needless violence, and all the social classes will be reduced to the lowest level of śūdras. Cows will be like goats, spiritual hermitages will be no different from mundane houses, and family ties will extend no further than the immediate bonds of marriage. Most plants and herbs will be tiny, and all trees will appear like dwarf śamī trees. Clouds will be full of lightning, homes will be devoid of piety, and all human beings will have become like asses. At that time, the Supreme Personality of Godhead will appear on the earth. Acting with the power of pure spiritual goodness, He will rescue eternal religion.

Right now we can see many atheists on this planet. By the end of this Yuga all religions will be forgotten and people become atheists. Verse says ***pāsaṇḍa-pracure dharme***: which means dharma will be atheistic. Lord Vishnu will come as Kalki and restore Sanatana Dharma (eternal dharma).

Answer (score 1):

There is no destruction at the end of a Yuga, so yes they can survive. a complete cycle of all the Yugas is called a Mahayuga. 1,000 mahayugas (4,320,000,000 human years) constitute a single day of Brahma - a single kalpa. A day of Brahma starts with the creation or emanation of the universe and terminates with the dissolution back into the Absolute. The higher worlds survive. So religions can survive from Yuga to the next (It doesn't say if they actually will or not), but they cannot survive after a day of Brahma. The current Brahma survives for 100 Brahma years and then there is the grand dissolution where all spheres of beings dissolve into the Absolute. After a Brahma century of re-absorption, there is a new Brahma and a new emanation.

It would appear according to some interpretations that every new emanation has the same events occur again in the same manner and sequence.

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said that both Buddha and Jesus were incarnations.

These different religions exist and moksha is possible but very difficult to attain through other religions. Swami Vivekananda said "This Moksha-path is only in India and nowhere else. Hence is true the oft-repeated saying that Mukta souls are only here in India and in no other country. But it is equally true that in the future they will be in other countries as well; that is well and good, and a thing of great pleasure to us." (C.W. V. 5, p 446)

Comment: Thank you. I don't think those religions will survive after the end of the yuga because at the end of the kali yuga, satya yuga comes which means that dharma is well established in it and that the people doesn't find differences between one another. In order to be so, there must not be any conflicts between the religions, which is possible only if Hinduism alone exist.

Comment: Though Buddha and Jesus were incarnations, I don't think moksha will be possible in other religions because as said by Lord Krishna, to attain moksha one must worship me and not the demigods. Buddha and Jesus can be said as demigods because they are not in the 10 avatars of Lord Vishnu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an accurate answer but here are some points that may help:

After the end of yuga a sort of transition happens over a period called yuga sandhi. As we go into each yuga, dharma, the principles of religion decline by one quarter at a time. The devastation doesn't happen after each yuga but it happens after about 71 yuga-cycles (end of  each Manu) and 1000 yuga cycles (end of Brahma's day).

I see most of the non sanatana-dharma religions (including Buddhism) as temporary arrangements so their specific details may not be part of the great Vedic literarture.

1. However Lord Buddha's incarnation is predicted in Srimad Bhagavatam
2. I heard some things like (yet to see specific scriptural citations) Jesus Christ is an avatar of Lord Siva.
3. Didn't come across anything about Prophet Mohammad

There is no word Hindu in Vedic literature and sanatana-dharma (correct replace term for Hinduism) deals mainly with impersonalism (brahman and paramatma aspects) and personalism (personal bhagavan aspect) as transcendental subjects. In that sense depending on what Christians and Muslims beleive they can also be counted in one of two. It seems mormons are just fruitive workers like some of the Vedic followers who want to go to svarga or have a position of Brahma. Some Christians believe in a personal eternal God and themselves as eternal servants. As far as I found with my contact with some Muslims they seem to be believe in an impersonal aspect of God. So when you say does these exist after the yuga the conceptions into which they fall always exist.